# Windows Vista: Changing the default action when double-clicking a folder

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I have a number of folders lying on my Windows Vista desktop. When I double-click a folder Windows Explorer is launched. How do you change this so that a Windows Explorer alternative (e.g. Total Commander) is launched instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hit on Google.

http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=1189